# Google BillingClient queryProductDetailsAsync for current subscribers detect active offers

Tags: android, billingclient

Google BillingClient's documentation is not very specific if we can rely on queryProductDetailsAsync to know if the user has any active offer or not.
From what i'm seeing in the docs it looks like these queries are always user bound, ie. it will return the offers that are either currently applied to that user's products or the user is eligible to get, but i'm yet to find that explicit in the docs.
Has anyone come across anything like this?